# LARAVEL 5: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to update an "contrato" from a user but i am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' contrato' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `contratos` where ` contrato` = 3261026)
```

I've try to solved but i cant see my miskate.

In the controller, i am seeting a validation where i can modify the "contrato" ignoring the user, that way i wont get the error "this contrato exist."

**controller code**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $contrato = Contrato::find($id);

    $request->validate([
            'contrato' => [
                'required','numeric','unique:contratos, contrato, '.$user->id' ','digits:7',
                new ValidateContrato,
            ],
        ]
    );

    $contrato->update([
        'contrato'  => $request->contrato,
    ]);

    session()->flash('message','¡Su contrato fue editado satisfactoriamente!');

    return redirect()->route('contratos.index');
}
```

**user model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function contrato(){
        return $this->hasMany(Contrato::class);
    }

    public function card(){
        return $this->hasMany(Card::class);
    }

    public function pago(){
        return $this->hasMany(Pago::class);
    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'lastname', 'alias', 'cedula', 'email', 'email2', 'password', 'cellphone', 'homephone', 'faxphone', 'officephone', 'born_date', 'terms_accepted', 'invoice_by_mail',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

**contrato model**

```
class Contrato extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'contrato', 'user_id', 'emition_date', 'payment_reference',
    ];
}
```

Comment: DOes the column exist in table ?

Comment: There is a typo. You've written a space before the column name within the backticks, so you wrote `[s]contrato` instead of `contrato`. (As the formatter won't work otherwise i replace the space with `[s]`)

Comment: Thx for the simple fix! :)

Comment: This fix 1 issue, but this:
    `'unique:contratos,contrato,'.$user->id,`
is not ignoring the user so laravel can modify a record from the same user even if is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in this line:

```
'required','numeric','unique:contratos, contrato, '.$user->id' ','digits:7',
```

Remove the space before `contrato`. The line should look like this:

```
'required','numeric','unique:contratos,contrato,'.$user->id' ','digits:7',
```

Comment: Nice Observation

Comment: This fix 1 issue, but this: `unique:contratos,contrato,'.$user->id`, is not ignoring the user so laravel can modify a record from the same user even if is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your validation rule like:

```
$request->validate([
        'contrato' => [
            'required,numeric,unique:contratos,contrato,'.$user->id.',digits:7',
            new ValidateContrato,
        ],
```